# how to update fragment using the viewpager in android

Tags: android

My problem is how can i update list view within  view pager.
i am using the same  4 tabs having a list view with different arraylist set to there adapters.
I am using only one fragment and bases of tabs position I am loading different list data to inner fragment arrayAdapter. Also I have two buttons one is delete and another one is Add.
What I want: If I press the add button then it should add new data to the array list(based on the tab position add the new add to respective arrayList) and refresh the listview data.

Answer (score 0):

Use onPageSelected(int position) from your Pager to figure out at what Array you have to add items.

Then, after you add that new item to Array, you should set ArrayAdapter again for those ListView since list has changed.

Then call notifyDataSetChanged() on your Adapter object once you've modified the data in that adapter to refresh ListView.

Edit: you don't have to use constructor for changing ArrayAdapter, this should work:

```
ArrayAdapter.clear();
ArrayAdapter.addAll(changedArray);
ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```